# Unable to switch scenes after nesting

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I was able to switch to the employee list, but I get the back button. So I tried to nest them into separate scenes, but when I tried to nest the scenes, it will no longer navigate to the next scene. Here is my code.

At the bottom of my index actions file, I have an action called loginUserSuccess, inside the loginUserSuccess action is the line Actions.employeeList().

I'm still using the same scene key of employeeList.

src/actions/index.js

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
  EMAIL_CHANGED,
  LOGIN_USER,
  LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  PASSWORD_CHANGED
} from './types';

export const emailChanged = text => {
  return {
    type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};

export const passwordChanged = text => {
  return {
    type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};

export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
      });
  };
};

const loginUserFail = dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL });
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
  console.log(Actions.currentScene);
  Actions.employeeList();
  console.log(Actions.currentScene);
};
```

Inside this router file, I have nested the login scene inside the auth scene and I nested the employeeList scene inside the main scene. This is where my issue with switching scenes started.

src/Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import EmployeeList from './components/EmployeeList';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  const { navigationBarTitleStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="auth">
          <Scene
            key="login"
            component={LoginForm}
            title="Please Login"
            titleStyle={navigationBarTitleStyle}
            initial
          />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="main">
          <Scene
            key="employeeList"
            component={EmployeeList}
            title="Employee List"
            titleStyle={navigationBarTitleStyle}
          />
        </Scene>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
};

const styles = {
  navigationBarTitleStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem? I'm following the guide The Complete React Native and Redux Course on Udemy by Stephen Grider, but react native is such a fast moving target.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was, I needed to change my Actions.employeeList(); to Actions.main(); in the src/actions/index.js file.

I needed to target the parent instead of the child inside that scene. It will then load the first scene inside of the main scene. I could also set initial on the employeeList to be more clear about it.